# android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window?

Tags: android, android-layout

I want to show a popup menu in my activity,so I am calling the popup method on onCreate but I got this exception.Can anybody help? I could not understand ,I am a begginer to java and android.

```
   android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token null is not valid; is your activity running?
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.setView(ViewRootImpl.java:700)
        at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:345)
        at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:224)
        at android.view.WindowManagerImpl$CompatModeWrapper.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:149)
        at android.view.Window$LocalWindowManager.addView(Window.java:554)
        at android.widget.PopupWindow.invokePopup(PopupWindow.java:1013)
        at android.widget.PopupWindow.showAtLocation(PopupWindow.java:856)
        at android.widget.PopupWindow.showAtLocation(PopupWindow.java:820)
        at project1.me.com.cookbookintent.ImageViewActivity.initiatePopupWindow(ImageViewActivity.java:271)
        at project1.riafy.com.cookbookintent.ImageViewActivity.onCreate(ImageViewActivity.java:91)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5206)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1094)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2074)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2135)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:140)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1237)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4921)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1027)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:794)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Method to show Popup window

```
 public void initiatePopupWindow() {
    try {

        LayoutInflater inflater;
        inflater = (LayoutInflater) ImageViewActivity.this
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.popupmenu, (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.popup_element));
        pwindo = new PopupWindow(layout, WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, true);
        pwindo.showAtLocation(layout, Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);

        // pwindo.setFocusable(true);
        pwindo.setOutsideTouchable(true);
        //  pwindo.showAsDropDown();
        Button btnStopUpload = (Button) layout.findViewById(R.id.btn_upload);
        btnStopUpload.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
              //  mNotifyManager.cancel(MY_NOTIFICATION_ID);
                //  mTask.cancel(true);
                Log.e(TAG, "Notification Cancelled ");
                // mTask.cancel(true);
              /*  Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "Upload Cancelled", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();*/
                Intent i=new Intent(ImageViewActivity.this,MyService.class);
                //stopService(i);
                ImageViewActivity.this.stopService(i);
                ImageViewActivity.this.finish();
            }
        });


        Button btnCancelPopup = (Button) layout.findViewById(R.id.btn_cancel);

        btnCancelPopup.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                pwindo.dismiss();

            }
        });
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                "POPUP Rejected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Log.e("COOKBOOK", "I got an error", e);
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: You can only show a popup if it's started from a currently running activity.

Comment: I am callling the method when the activity is first created.

Comment: What is `R.id.popup_element` in `inflater.inflate()` referring to?

Comment: Sorry may be this is the problem,i just copied this code from A TUTORIAL , can you help me to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is too early to create PopUp Windows onCreate. Even you do it after

```
setContentView( R.layout.activity_main );
```

statement. You have to do it a second later. You can use this.

```
new Handler(  ).postDelayed( new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            initiatePopupWindow();
        }
    }, 1000 );
```

This is example. I don't know how your code works. But you have to give a time to Android os to create and initialize views. ***setContentView()*** method call doesn't mean views are completely created.

**EDIT:** If you create PopUp in fragment's ***onCreate()***, this is wrong too. Because fragment's view are completely initialized at ***onActivityCreated()*** method. You can just call your PopUp initializer method ***onActivityCreated()*** inside the fragment.